# mysql join issue with where condition

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, inner-join

I have two tables

```
  Profile                         Status
  profile_id |name | active       status_id |profile_id|age
```

I need to get the status where the profile  "active" is 1 and the status age is greater than 10

This query returns when the profile_id are matching

```
  Select * from 
  status LEFT JOIN ON status.profile_id = profile.profile_id
```

but when I place a where condition it displays nothing

```
  Select * from 
  status LEFT JOIN ON status.profile_id = profile.profile_id
  where profile.active= 1 and status.age > 40
```

Is the left join the right type of JOIN?

Comment: you missed second table name

Comment: profile.enabled should be profile.active

Comment: A `Status` without an profile doesn't make sense. Because you want results with a certain status age, it should be an `INNER JOIN`. If you want some profiles without status too, then you would use a `FROM Profile LEFT JOIN status` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct `profile.enabled` to `profile.active` and also you are `table name` missing on LEFT JOIN. Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM status
INNER JOIN profile ON status.profile_id = profile.profile_id
WHERE profile.active = 1
  AND status.age > 40
```

Comment: it works but it even works with inner join. which one is recommended?

Comment: As per my suggesssion inner join if you want to status of whose profile is created?

Comment: @meWantToLearn: if you need an existing `age` and only `active` profiles then you need an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the Join table name and `profile.enabled` should be `profile.active` Try this:

```
 Select * 
 from 
      status  
      LEFT JOIN profile ON status.profile_id = profile.profile_id
 where 
      profile.active = 1 and status.age > 40
```

OR

```
 Select * 
 from 
      status  
      LEFT JOIN profile ON status.profile_id = profile.profile_id and status.age > 40
 where 
      profile.active = 1
```

Comment: In this case the `LEFT JOIN` will implicitly be converted to an `INNER JOIN` because of your `WHERE` condition. See the answer of @Rahul.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM Profile p,
     Status s
WHERE p.profile_id=s.profile_id
  AND p.active=1
  AND s.age>10
```

Also please cross check your second query, it has field enabled, which does not exists in profile.

Comment: You should avoid the syntax for joins, it's old, uses different syntax on various databases (+ vs * etc) and is just plain hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

it seem to miss the table name in left join clause.
In your post you ask for age greater than 10 and in the sql order it's 40.

change

```
Select * from 
  status LEFT JOIN ON status.profile_id = profile.profile_id
  where profile.enabled = 1 and status.age > 40
```

into

```
  Select * from  status LEFT JOIN profile ON status.profile_id =
profile.profile_id   where profile.active= 1 and status.age > 40
```

Answer (score 0):

if have missed table name for second table.

Your query should be like this:

```
SELECT s.* FROM 
  status  s LEFT JOIN profile p ON s.profile_id = p.profile_id
  WHERE p.active= 1 and s.age > 40
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing 'profile' table after `LEFT JOIN`

```
 SELECT * FROM 
      status LEFT JOIN profile 
      ON status.profile_id = profile.profile_id
      AND profile.active= 1 AND status.age > 40
```